# Unable to update the xamarin.support.v4 packages

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

while updating my NuGet packages I am getting this issue

Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0-rc1' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.5.253-pre5 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)'.

Can any one guide me for this issue

Thank You

Comment: 1) I don't recommend using `rcX` packages, as they are not stable. 2) I think you should update Xamarin.Forms too

Comment: Thank you @vlad Matvienko ,I updated the Xamarin.Forms to latest version (prerelease 2.3.5.256 ) even its showing the same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not update Support libraries by your self. Instead update only Xamarin.Forms package and it updates his dependencies automatically. 
Now, try to uninstall all Support libraries and Xamarin.Forms, install Xamarin.Forms again and it would add all dependencies needed.
As a reference, take a look at [this](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/170012/#Comment_170012).

Comment: Yes I understood it and reinstalled the Xamarin.forms

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar the other week (blindly clicked update and it all went wrong), my solution was to downgrade Xamarin Android Support (I'm on 23.3.0) although I'm only using Xamarin Forms 2.3.4.247 I believe the issues is common.

From memory this was a bit of a pain and had to actually remove them one by one and add them back in (maybe take a screenshot of what packages are installed so you don't forget!), but 23.3.0 was the magic support version.

HTH

Comment: Thank You @AndyFlisher , okay I will do it and see

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1.

Update xamarin forms to latest version.

Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 25.4.0-rc1 is having some dependence on latest xamarin.forms

Solution 2.

Install older version of Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 .
Check the version dependence before installing and ensure that older version do not have dependence on xamarin forms.